# How to check if uploaded image is a desired image and not any other undesirable image?

Tags: php, image, verify

I am building a website where a user can lodge a complaint regarding garbage problem at his/her place by uploading a photo of that garbage.

I want a mechanism or a code by which I can check and verify that the uploaded image is an image of garbage and not any other undesirable image.

I am using PHP language in my project. Can somebody suggest a PHP code or any other appropriate code to carry out above verification?

Please help...

Comment: garbage recognition, interesting... :) I really don't know, but admin will have to work a lot...

Comment: Can you search for library for garbage recognition, I've never seen or heard an implementation of this

Comment: Actually i want some mechanism to compare both the images i.e uploaded image with a image of garbage and to check whether they are similar or not

Comment: @Abhijit, yes, we understand, maybe you can try this: http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle/php. or this https://github.com/kennethrapp/phasher

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  So is garbage. =)